# Syntax error when updating sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I', trying to update my database using this.

```
String dd = "1-PC CHICKEN & RICE";
SQLiteDatabase db2 = openOrCreateDatabase("order",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("Description",(((TextView) findViewById(R.id.etoriginal)).getText().toString()));
db1.update("list", values, "Description ="+ dd ,null);
```

But i got this error in my log cat

```
07-04 16:20:00.659: E/AndroidRuntime(21504): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CHICKEN": syntax error: , while compiling: UPDATE list SET Image=? WHERE Description =1-PC CHICKEN & RICE
```

I can't figure out what is causing this

Comment: sorry i'm new to stackoverflow and i can't see how to accept the answer. can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the condition in quotes:

```
db1.update("list", values, "Description ='" + dd + "'", null);
```

Comment: Note that this is not the safest solution, since it will fail if `dd` contains quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the value of `dd` rather than embedding it directly in your query. Try this instead:

```
db1.update("list", values, "Description = ?", new String[] { dd });
```

Wrapping `dd` in quotes, as dbaseman says, will also work in this particular case but will fail if `dd` happens to contain quote characters itself (`"1-PC FROGS' LEGS"`). Supplying it as a separate parameter, as I'm doing here, is generally safer and more efficient.